# Early stages of a police / surveillance state, experiment leading to totaliarian government

Tags: technology, economy, government, crime, dictatorship

A democratic government starts tightening its grip on the citizens by tiny steps, slowly but surely they advance towards a state that resembles China today.

In their first step, they start a seemingly harmless survey: they track everyone's position via mobile. The data is supposed to be anonymous, but it's really not, as carriers save it alongside the phone number which is bound to the real name and in most cases an ID. Most people don't even know - it didn't break the news, as they claim it's only to improve infrastructure.

What would be the most dangerous thing they could do with this data?

Comment: This seems a bit broad; the set of all things that could be done with personalised geolocation data is quite large, after all. You should perhaps refine your question to ask about some specific things, to avoid the risk of it being closed.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time getting it to be more precise - it's based on a real situation and I want to fictionalize it to show the danger.

Comment: There are 3 questions in this post. We prefer 1 question per post. Please comply to our policy. It is fine to spread the questions over multiple, related posts.

Comment: @L.Dutch Thank you. I'm going to reduce it to the question I need answered the most.

Comment: "They" already track the position of every mobile phone. "They" *have* to do this, because this is how mobile telephony works; it the network did not track the phone it wouldn't know how to make it ring when someone is calling it. In most countries of this world, the mobile telephony operators are obliged by law to let the police and first responders know the position of a mobile device, to the best of the network's knowledge. But, fortunately, in most countries of this world it is pretty easy to get a mobile device which is not linked to any name or ID.

Comment: How do you measure danger?

Comment: AlexP is spot on.  Furthermore, most countries, especially first-world countries, have laws or regulations which (theoretically) limit how this information is used - both by the carrier and the government.  Whether or not these laws are correct (or are being obeyed) is a matter of debate

Comment: Right now I am looking at the real-world example of Spain, where they will conduct a mass-surveillance experiment. It's exactly the data you are talking about (carrier tracking, tied to phone number) which will be given to a national institute (i.e. the government, though indirectly). This is a massive breach of privacy rights imo. I know it is already being done and this is nothing new, but it's still something we should care about as it can quickly evolve into danger, right?

Answer (score 2):

The next step - and most dangerous - would be **identifying targets**.  This seems like a passive thing, but it's likely irreversible, and can directly lead to a systemic oppression against the people.

Knowing where people are gives you immense insight into their lives.  Here's a list of some things that information will provide you:

- Map out everyone's relationships - who they see, when, how frequently, etc
- Know where everyone works, shops, etc (and thereby estimate their income)
- Identify people's religions (where they go to church/synagogue/mosque/temple/etc)
- Know people's shopping habits
- ... and so on

On an individual level you can cripple people's lives (block off their roads to work, get to their friends, shut down their favorite bar, blackmail [we know you're cheating on your significant other], and so on).

On a social level a totalitarian government **is unlikely to take action at this stage**.  Instead, they would proceed with **Identify "problem" citizens and groups**.  For example, if the government hates guns, then who goes to gun ranges? If they hate [religion], who goes [religion]'s building?  If the government is afraid [race], then identify not only everyone of [race], but those who frequently interact with [race] (frequent interaction means increased risk of being sympathetic to their departure).  If the government wants to limit medical expenses, who frequents hospitals - and who are their families, friends, lovers, etc?

Normally it would be impossible to track everyone's relationships.  A random farmer in Kansas has a business connection in Idaho who's wife grew up in the Bronx, so if you try to take out the Bronx, then wife pressures hubby to get in touch with farmer in Kansas to supply aid in the rebellion.  *However*, if the government knows all these connections, they can prepare for this eventually and put safeguards in place.

The most powerful piece of this means *knowing who to attack first and how to proceed from there*.  As Martin Niemöller, regarding the Nazis, [famously wrote](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/martin-niemoeller-first-they-came-for-the-socialists):

> First they came for the socialists, and I did not speak out—because I was not a socialist.
>
> Then they came for the trade unionists, and I did not speak out— because I was not a trade unionist.
>
> Then they came for the Jews, and I did not speak out—because I was not a Jew.
>
> Then they came for me—and there was no one left to speak for me.

In today's world, maybe they first go for *farmers* - the government needs to "ensure equal food access to all people".  Or maybe they start with religion X - "we support all religions, but cannot tolerate the violence of X".  Who knows?

If the end goal is totalitarianism, then the way to get there is *building an action plan that prevents the people arming or rebelling against them*.  It may sound extreme, but while it would normally be difficult (if not impossible) to know all the connections and sympathies of people, simple tracking movement will give you insight into their relationships, opinions, statuses, etc.  And *that* information let's the government (a) make a plan, and (b) identify their targets.

Finally, *even if they stop tracking movements*, they already have a map of society.  It would take years - perhaps even decades - before that information would become obsolete.  Once the data is collected, it cannot be uncollected.

Comment: Good answer, but the system as described only tracks people's location. Your example relationship of a farmer in Kansas with a business connection in Idaho is effectively invisible to this system - those people likely don't interact physically very often, if at all. In the modern world, lots of communication occurs without physical proximity (especially among fringe political groups), which is a huge blind spot for this system.

Comment: @NuclearWang you'd be surprised.  If they can get their names, they can get *a lot of other stuff*.  So the farmer's childhood home address is next door to the guy from Idaho.  Once a year (Thanksgiving) their phones are in the same location.  Clearly they're still friends.

Answer (score 1):

"The worst" can be a bit subjective, but let's give a try:

**Use it to solve actual crimes** - does not sound sinister, so you may end up with people actually being fine with the system and wanting it to be expanded. That would be actually the most conductive thing for thriving of the regime.

**Use it to track who is the opposition** - always useful, but presumably should be backed up and used many years later

**Selective enforcement of law** - people commit plenty of misdemeanours in their life. With proper enforcement system you could properly target the trouble makers or use it to blackmail. No political prisoners, but plenty of people who clearly drive above the speed limit. (apparently the UK government tried this recently in case of Tommy Robinson and his alleged contempt of court...)

**Dox disliked opposition** - Sending hired thugs may raise too many eyebrows in such early phase. But let's say that pending who is your enemy you could for example give their data to someone who personally hates them. Do you consider nationalists as evil trouble makers? Then leak data of their families to Antifa.

Comment: I've never heard of Antifa going after the *families* of nationalists, only the nationalists themselves. I've certainly never heard anyone say "Punch a Nazi and also his wife and children". Why not just leak the data of the nationalists themselves?

Comment: @F1Krazy Now you have.  https://www.nbcnews.com/news/all/antifa-group-chants-outside-vandalizes-fox-commentator-tucker-carlson-s-n934131  Also, non-Antifa leftist. "We've got to get the children connected to their parents..." https://www.cnn.com/2018/06/25/politics/maxine-waters-trump-officials/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Blackmailing seems like a huge thing to me because it can easily lead to the next step: broaden your spy network by making people spy on their neighbors. I liked that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the location of many non anonymous people is a dangerous leak of their privacy.

**Situation A:**

Mark is married to Sharon, but has an affair with Brooke, who is married with Arnold. They meet in a hotel while Sharon knows that Mark is in a business meeting, while Arnold knows that Brook is at the hairdresser. Whoever knows the location of Mark and Brooke can blackmail them.

Real life example: an Italian football team was found guilty of having illegally tracked its players via their mobile phones.

If you think that if you are not hiding anything you have nothing to worry about, look at

**situation B:**

Police officers want to install monitoring devices in your house, just because they are paranoid. Knowing that every Thursday from 17:00 to 19:00 your house is empty (you are playing badminton, your wife is buying groceries and your son is at the baseball training, as testified by your mobiles) gives them leeway in doing so with less worries of being found out.

Answer (score 0):

## Statistical processing

Tracking one person is hard work and done manually. You can use it to solve crimes, track opponents affairs etc, but that's specific and time consuming. It's when you treat the data set as a whole for patterns that the population as a whole starts having problems.

Group associations for example, all these people were in X location that was associated with a protest. Many of them accumulated Y location or came from Z town. Everyone who passed through Y location or Z town in that time range is now on the list.

*I don't yet care who any of them are.*

A significant percentage of that group are converging on location W. You have a choice, continue to monitor associations, or just round up everyone in location W for reeducation.

*I still neither know, nor care, who any of them are. Your data remains anonymous, or more specifically pseudonymous.*

## Association tracking

You're up for reeducation, but nobody works alone. Given the history of your movements from your phone I have a list of people you associate with. I also have a list of they associate with, if there's significant group association, and especially if there's association with other people due for reeducation, then I have a long list of people to either monitor or reeducate. That probably includes all of your close family, eggs and omelettes as they say.

Answer (score 0):

Telecom operators already have to know the cell location of every phone registered on their network, so they can get the right data to the right phone number (which is inherently linked with an actual identity). That's an unavoidable part of having a working mobile network. But that's just the cell location at an instant in time.

I think what you're suggesting is that the government now stores this data for subsequent analysis. That allows them to do arbitrary reconstruction of the movements of any individual they like. They can tell what shops you visit, they can cross-reference locations to work out who you hang out with and therefore build a social graph of everyone in the country. That even means they can extrapolate with a fairly high degree of confidence to fill in the social graph even for people who don't have mobile phones.

From the shops, clubs, premises you visit they can work out your interests, social class, political leanings, what football team you support, schools your children attend. They can spot patterns, say you follow the same route to work every day or you go to a particular pub every Saturday evening. Then, for any given resistance movement that might arise, if they identify one member, they know who else to round up. They know where to round them up. They have all the leverage they need ("We know where your children are. Look, Agent Smith is sat outside their school right now. I think it's about time you told us who else is in the resistance and confessed to {arbitrary list of crimes}.")

In short, they can reconstruct in great detail every bit of data about how you live your life. If you then consider that at the same time they can probably also obtain call metadata (who you call and when, but not the actual conversation) and internet metadata (what sites you visit, but not the content) then there is nothing they can't find out about you. There is zero privacy in such a state. If they want your actual conversation data, they know the places you go and your phone number so they have everything they need to set up a Stingray to man-in-the-middle your actual phone calls and get that too.

They can also carry out a stitch-up: they know where you are so they can set up a honey trap. They know where you have been, if they fish hard enough they can probably find a series of criminal occurrences you've randomly been in the vicinity of. "Has anyone considered that Joe Bloggs might have carried out these crimes? Look, he was here, and here, and here, he could have done them all!" Even if it can be disproved it costs you a lot in time and effort and money to clear your name, and partly it will never be cleared because people think there's no smoke without fire.

By the way (and as I'm sure you know from your comment on the question) all of this capability already exists. Perhaps it's already being used. How would we even know? The data never has to appear in court, its existence allows a malevolent government to deal with people in a manner that never needs to involve a court (not necessarily lethal, disgracing a person and destroying them socially can be just as effective if not more so).